# I want to discard changes made to the body of a mail item

Tags: c++, outlook, outlook-addin

I have created an Outlook add-in. When any mail is opened/previewed in Outlook, I want my add-in to update the body of the mail. And when the mail is closed or the preview is closed, I want the changes to be reverted back to the original changes.

For this I have tracked the SelectionChange event.
Inside its handler:

1. I have obtained the Active Explorer using mApp->ActiveExplorer(&mExplorer) function
2. Then obtained selection from explorer using mExplorer->get_Selection(&lSelection)
3. Then obtained the mail item from Selection using QueryInterface()
4. On this mail item, I am updating the body using put_HTMLBody() function

Now, when the user clicks on any other mail, I want to discard the changes I made.
However, the mail item gets saved and Outlook also creates another mail as well.

I want to discard the changes in all cases like if the user double clicks and opens the mail and closes it.

How can I discard the changes made to any mail item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do that. Temporary changing anything in Outlook never works well. If you want to display your own data, display it in your own control / custom form /etc.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry for the useful information. Can you please clarify what problems can occur or what does not work well? If showing own control or custom form is not a possible solution for me, can you please suggest how can I achieve the same in Outlook?

Comment: Problems? Sure: your temporary data can get saved if the user hits Ctrl+S. Outlook can display a prompt to save the changes, etc. What is it exactly that you are trying to achieve? Why are you trying to replace Outlook data?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The functionality that I want to achieve is as follows: When the user sends the mail, the actual mail body is sent as an attachment. At the receiver end, based on some conditions, user will be able to see the mail body. If the condition succeeds, the contents of that attachment are to be displayed in the mail body but it should not be persisted in the mail. How is it possible to achieve the same?

Comment: Design your own custom form that displays any data you want any way yo use fit. When the message arrives, change the message class to that of your custom form to make sure Outlook will invoke it instead of the built-in form.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitry for your suggestions.